# Strange error while trying to use desktop bridge for wpf

Tags: desktop-bridge

I am trying to use Visual studio project template for desktop bridge to add   to wpf app and it will not build successfully and shows this strange warning that i have attached.

[warning when building desktop bridge project template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHgwr.png)

i had followed this post on official documentation :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net
and before that i had used this blog post to add winmd and runtime to my project:
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/
and here is the code form Package.appxmanifest file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10" xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest" xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10" xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" xmlns:iot="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/iot/windows10" IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap iot">
  <Identity Name="09b95fbd-84cc-426f-9fd2-2c1d3d304fab" Publisher="CN=SO-PC-005" Version="1.0.0.0" />
  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>WapProjTemplate</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>SO-PC-005</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>
  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate" />
  </Resources>
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App" Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe" EntryPoint="$targetentrypoint$">
      <uap:VisualElements DisplayName="WapProjTemplate" Description="WapProjTemplate" BackgroundColor="transparent" Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png">
        </uap:DefaultTile>
      </uap:VisualElements>
    </Application>
  </Applications>
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <iot:Capability Name="systemManagement" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>
</Package>
```

I also would like to mention that i am trying to use windows.graphics.display for brightness override in a wpf app and it requires systemManagement capapbility. And also that my project builds successfully without packaging project but when I add packaging project to my wpf solution it will not build.

Comment: I would recommend including the exception message as text rather than as an image as links might be available if someone was viewing this question later.

Comment: i need atlease 10 reputations to post more than 10 links @VidmantasBlazevicius

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error on my machine using the exact same manifest that you have posted. Can you share a complete VS solution that demonstrates this error?

Comment: the error has to do with capabilities even if i do not add system management it still gives me same error on runfulltrust capability. you used manual method or visual studio ?? @StefanWickMSFT

Comment: I used visual studio to create a new desktop project with packaging project, then I copied over your package.appxmanifest file and everything still works.

Comment: when i build packaging project it wont build and gave me that error . have u tried adding a wpf project to application in packaging project ???

Comment: Yes, that's what I did. Can you share your repro project please? Otherwise this question is not actionable.